# Using like operator to check for pattern in hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql, sql-like

I need to retrieve the columns from a hive table that must begin with uppercase letter and end with digit.
I used this query

```
select * from tab1 where col1 like '[A-Z]%[0-9]';
```

But not able to retrieve the records ,getting only empty result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**rlike / regexp**

```
select * from tab1 where col1 rlike '^[A-Z].*[0-9]$';
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!.. Can you please provide a tutorial link for learning this reg expression... As I'm new to hive.

Comment: Please note that there are regular expression dialects and the rellevant one is PCRE **(1)** http://www.regular-expressions.info/ **(2)** http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Can you tell which kind of regexp should be used to validate the date format YYYY-MM-DD.?

Comment: The basic check would be: `select '2017-03-15' rlike '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}';` (`\\d` stands for digit), but I would recommend on another way: `select cast('2017-03-15' as date),cast('2017-01-32' as date);`